# How to move Header and Trailer from files to another file?

Tags: python, shell, powershell, unix

I have around 100 text files with close to thousand records in a folder. I want to copy header and trailer of these files into a new file with the file name of respective file.

So the output i want is as

```
File_Name,Header,Trailer
```

is this possible using Unix or Python?

Comment: I think you meant records per file not per folder?

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is with the bash shell in the folder containing the files:

```
for file in *; do echo "$file,$(head -1 $file),$(tail -1 $file)"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell-core one liner with aliases

```
 gci *.txt |%{"{0},{1},{2}" -f $_.FullName,(gc $_ -Head 1),(gc $_ -Tail 1)}|set-content .\newfile.txt
```